# Adding image files into JSON object and displaying it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am a total beginner at coding, and I signed up here just to ask this question. I'm wondering if any of you can point me to the right direction or help me out with this code. First off, my goal is to create an art portfolio that shows my art in a 3x3 format, basically the same format look as Instagram.

So I've done a lot of tinkering the past couple of weeks, working with a mentor and at first, he told me to display my images in a 3x3 format using just JavaScript. After doing that, I've been told to learn more about JSON and how to store images in a JSON object and display it in a 3x3 object exactly like before. At first, it turned out great with JavaScript but then after he told me to change it up by using JSON, my images don't display the same anymore. Now they are stacked on top of each other, vertically, and not 3x3 anymore. I've been comparing code with my old file and the latest one still turns out vertically stacked...

My current JS code:

```
var data = {
"images": [{
        "img": "img/balloon.jpg",
        "id": "balloon"
    },
    {
        "img": "img/cate.jpg",
        "id": "cate"

    },
    {
        "img": "img/dragon.jpg",
        "id": "dragon"
    },
    {
        "img": "img/Groot.jpg",
        "id": "groot"
    },
    {
        "img": "img/flareon.jpg",
        "id": "flareon"
    },
    {
        "img": "img/forest.jpg",
        "id": "forest"
    },
    {
        "img": "img/fox.jpg",
        "id": "fox"
    },
    {
        "img": "img/glaceon.jpg",
        "id": "glaceon"
    },
    {
        "img": "img/majora.jpg",
        "id": "majora"
    }, 
] };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Art Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">





</head>

<header>
    <center>
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="centered-text"> My Art Gallery</div>
        </div>
    </center>
</header>




<body>

    <script>
        var fs = require('./img');
        var files = fs.readdirSync('./img');
        function myMessage() {
            if (files == null) {
                return " sorry something went wrong ";
            } else {
                // print files
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        document.write(myMessage());
    </script>



    <p>
        <div class="tn-container tn left">
            <div id="profile-picture">
                <script>
                    var myProfile = document.createElement("img");
                    myProfile.setAttribute("src", "img/Me1.jpg");
                    document.getElementById("profile-picture").prepend(myProfile);
                </script>

            </div>

            <p>
                <div class="block_1 hline-bottom "></div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </p>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>



            <div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>

            <div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="art" id="images"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</html>

<script type="text/javascript " src="script.js "></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

```
data.images.forEach(function(obj) {
var img = new Image();
img.src = obj.img;
img.setAttribute("class", "art");
document.getElementById("images").appendChild(img);
```

As you can see, I've been using containers and rows to make my format 3x3. It was fine before until I started inserting the images into JSON object. Images are showing which is great but now they are vertically stacked. I just want it 3x3 like before :/

This is my first time posting here on Stack Overflow so I apologize in advance if my question isn't clear or if I'm not showing my code correctly. Also I can post up my old files to compare

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `fs` and `require` are `Node.js` modules, meaning they exist on the server, and are not defined on the client (i.e. the HTML web pages). Trying to include that code in an HTML `<script>` tag will not work. In your case, I suggest removing the top two `<script>` blocks, as they will do nothing but write "sorry something went wrong" at the top of your page.

As for your problem of images being "stacked together", that is because you are trying to write to multiple HTML elements with the same `id` value. `id` must be unique for every element on a page. If you try to assign multiple things the same `id`, then usually only the first element with that id will work, because `document.getElementById` will stop searching after the first match. Even that behavior is not necessarily guaranteed. Never give multiple elements the same `id`.

To solve the problem, you can change the `id` value of the `<div>` elements where you want the images to go to exactly match the id attribute of your JSON data, and change your `document.getElementById("images")` to `document.getElementById(obj.id)`.

Note that this is not a very good solution, because it ties your data to the layout of the webpage by requiring the data file to know exactly what the `id` values on your page are. I suggest you look up and learn how to use `document.getElementsByName()` or `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will do more solid research. I also forgot to point out to disregard the whole "sorry something went wrong" snippet...it was just me testing something else out that my mentor told me to do haha.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I'm not very good at JavaScript, so this answer might not be the best one out there, but it does what it's supposed to.

```js
//here's your JSON
var data = [{
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/abinav_t/128.jpg",
        "id": "balloon"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ritu/128.jpg",
        "id": "cate"

    },
    {
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/zeldman/128.jpg",
        "id": "dragon"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg",
        "id": "groot"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/abinav_t/128.jpg",
        "id": "flareon"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ritu/128.jpg",
        "id": "forest"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/zeldman/128.jpg",
        "id": "fox"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg",
        "id": "glaceon"
    },
    {
        "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/abinav_t/128.jpg",
        "id": "majora"
    }, 
];

//variable to keep a track of the image no.
var i=0;

//looping through each "col-sm-4" to add the images
data.forEach(function(item) {
 document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-4")[i].innerHTML="<img src='"+item.img+"'/>";
  i++;
});
```

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

And here's the CodePen: https://codepen.io/devnathjoydeep/pen/JBmmaq